# Mandarin equivalent of "㗎喇"?

Tags: translation, cantonese, topolect

Cantonese has the modal particle: 㗎喇

Canto-Mando Dictionary says:

1.表示有把握，认可

2.表示说理，警告

Is there a mandarin equivalent?

Comment: I think it's similar to "...的啦"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

㗎喇 is a combination of multiple Cantonese sentence final particles (SFPs):

- 㗎 `gaa3` is a contraction of 嘅呀 `ge3 aa3`.

  - 嘅 `ge3` is directly equivalent to Mandarin's 的 `de` in meaning and usage.
  - 呀 `aa3` is used in Cantonese to soften the tone of a sentence. I don't believe Mandarin has a direct standardized equivalent to it, but some Mandarin speakers do use it in a similar manner.
- 喇 `laa3` is directly equivalent to Mandarin's SFP 了 `le`. Both of these words are actually cognate to one another, ultimately having been descended from 來 (note that this only applies to Mandarin's sentence-final 了; its post-verb 了 `le` actually is descended from 了 `liǎo`). Mandarin chose 了 to represent this word; written Cantonese isn't very standardized, so people have variously represented it using the characters 喇, 嚹, or 啦.

Given this, the Mandarin equivalent could be 的了 `de le`. While I noted there was no direct standard Mandarin equivalent for Cantonese's 呀, some speakers do use it. In Mandarin though, it would be attached after 了 rather than after 的; like Cantonese, it gets contracted as well, changing 了 `le` to 啦 `la`; the final result would be 的啦 `de la`, as @Stan mentioned in his comment.